# Obtener valor de un atributo en jquery al marcarlo

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un input tal que así

```
<input type="checkbox" id="numero-id="' + numeroID + '" />
```

Como saco el valor de `numeroID` ?

Tengo muchos input

```
<input type="checkbox" id="numero-id=6" />
<input type="checkbox" id="numero-id=2" />
<input type="checkbox" id="numero-id=3" />
<input type="checkbox" id="numero-id=7" />
<input type="checkbox" id="numero-id=1" />
<input type="checkbox" id="numero-id=8" />
<input type="checkbox" id="numero-id=9" />
```

Quiero sacarlo cuando lo marque y solo el que marco

Es decir, si marco el que tiene `numero-id=6`

```
<input type="checkbox" id="numero-id=6" />
```

quiero que me devuelva

```
6
```

Como seria el activador o el identificador a la hora de marcar?
Y la función para que recoga el valor de `numeroID` de ese input marcado?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Me parece que es esto lo que quieres:

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
 var id = this.id.replace("numero-id=","")
 $("#seleccionado").html(id)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="numero-id=6" />
<input type="checkbox" id="numero-id=2" />
<input type="checkbox" id="numero-id=3" />
<input type="checkbox" id="numero-id=7" />
<input type="checkbox" id="numero-id=1" />
<input type="checkbox" id="numero-id=8" />
<input type="checkbox" id="numero-id=9" />

<h1 id="seleccionado"> </h1>
```

Espero que te sirva

Answer (score 1):

Habrá muchísimas formas de llegar al mismo punto, a mí se me ocurre que, al hacer click en uno de los checkbox, recoger su id y separarlo por "=". Es decir:

```
$("input").click(function(event) {
    var id = event.target.id; 
    var num = id.split("="); 
    console.log(num[1]); 
});
```

De esta manera, con la primera línea de la función, recoges todo el id del checkbox clickado `numero-id=6` por ejemplo.

En la siguiente creas un array con dos valores, el 0 será lo anterior al igual y el 1 lo posterior, es decir `num = ["numero-id"]["6"]`

Con la última, muestras el valor del último elemento del array, que corresponde al número que buscas.

Se podría simplificar todo bastante de la siguiente forma:

```
$("input").click(function(event) {
        console.log(event.target.id.split("=")[1]);
});
```

Siendo `event.target.id.split("=")[1])` el valor que buscas.